# How can I call a function written in ARM assembly within C code?

Tags: c, assembly, extern

To be specific:

1. The arm assembly function is written in a separated file such as .S file or .asm file.
2. I need to call this function in main.c
3. The ARM assembly is in ARMv8 architecture.

I've written some testing code but it fails to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern int a_add(int a, int b);
int main(){
    int fi=5;
    int se=7;
    int result=a_add(fi, se);
    printf("result is %d", result);
    return 0;
}
```

And following is the assembly code.(a_add.S)

```
.section .text
.globl a_add
a_add:
    add x3,x1,x0
    mov x0,x3
    br x30
```

Does anyone know how I can fix these two files to let the a_add function work?
I haven't tried .asm file yet.

Any help is appreciated and please forgive if I made mistakes on expression, but I hope my question is clear.

Comment: This isn't standardized so it depends on compiler.

Comment: "Fails to work" is not a good description. Do you get an error? If so, what exactly? What command do you use to compile, assemble and link? If you get a runtime error, what does the debugger say?

Comment: I'm sorry that I made a mistake on the assembly code. It's “br x30" instead of "bx lr".

Comment: 1 error was reported. " error: ld returned 1 exit status". To be honest, I have no idea what this means. Another information given by the compiler is  using a_add(int,  int) function with it undefined. It seems that the compiler didn't link the two files together, and that's where my problem lies.

Comment: assembler function must be copatible wirh C calling covention, else hard fault occur. I dont know it is

Comment: in MOST envinronmests assembler equivalent shoul have initial `_` (asm: _a_add, C: a_add)

Comment: @JacekCz Not on ELF targets though.

Comment: @Lazyloper Can you post the complete compiler invocation and the complete error message you get?

Comment: @JacekCz: ELF environments (like Linux) don't prefix asm symbol names with underscores, but others do.  The `ld` error message looks linuxy.  I wondered if the OP was compiling as C++, resulting in name mangling.  We definitely need to know more about the build environment: compiler / assembler name, version, and options.  Or maybe they're compiling the C for an x86-64 desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the code by using extern "C" and have solved the problem. What needed is just claim the function as following in main.cpp or main.c

```
extern "C" {int a_add(int a, int b);}
```

Replace the old "extern" line by this line with "C".
This is helpful if the compiler is for C++ code instead of C code, basically by letting the function compiled in the way of C code, not C++ code.

I haven't made such test but I suppose if the compiler is C compiler, there won't be such a problem.

Comment: That's correct, if you'd compiled your code as C (like your `[c]` tag indicated you were), you wouldn't have needed this.  BTW, you can use `#ifdef __cplusplus` and put the `extern "C"` on a separate line to make code that does what you want in C++ as well as being valid C.

Answer (score 0):

**main.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>

extern int a_add(int, int);

int main() {
  int a = 5;
  int b = 3;
  printf("%d + %d = %d \n",  a, b, a_add(a, b));
}
```

**add.s**

```
        .text
        .global a_add
a_add:
        add     w0, w0, w1
        ret
```

Compiled with gcc (9.3.0) on an AArch64 machine (a docker container with ubuntu 20.04) using:

```
gcc main.c add.s -o run.exe && ./run.exe
```

A quick way to get the skeleton ready for a desired function in a target assembly would be:

1. Write a simple c function matching the signature of the desired function, e.g., for the add function above:

```
int a_add(int a, int b){
  return a + b;
}
```

2. Generate assembly for such C function to begin with.

```
gcc -S -O2 add.c
```

Note: Using higher optimisation level might produce less obvious code.

**Tip**: [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/YbWvPGx9h) is a good tool to know while playing around with the assembly.